# Recover true statistics for a union of subsamples - only data available are summary statistics for each subsample

Tags: descriptive-statistics, pooling

Let $a_1$, $a_2$, ...,$a_m$ be the samples of data, and let us further assume the only information we have about each sample is their *count/no. of samples*, *mean*, *standard deviation* and *median*.

The task I have set myself is to recover the true, or at least the best estimate possible, of the *mean*, *median* and *standard deviation* of the  union of these samples $a_1 \cup a_2 \cup ... \cup a_m$, which I will call $A$.

**Recover the Mean**

Recovering the mean is straightforward as we can just use the number of samples to recover the mean for $A$.

$$\bar{x}_1 = \frac{1}{n_1} \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n_1} x_i, \quad  \bar{x}_2 = \frac{1}{n_2} \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n_2} x_i \quad  ... \quad$\bar{x}_m = \frac{1}{n_m} \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n_m} x_i$$

$$ \bar{x}_A = \frac{n_1\bar{x}_1 + n_2\bar{x}_2 + ... + n_m\bar{x}_m}{n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_m} $$

**Recover the Standard Deviation**

This seems like it should be possible.

The standard deviation of a particular sample is defined as:
$$ s_i = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n_i} (x_k - \bar{x}_i)^2}{n_i-1}}$$

It seems to me, we could do the following to attempt to recover the *standard deviation* of $A$. Essentially we could assume a symmetric deviation about the subsample mean for each data point, half below, half above, and calculate the new whole sample standard deviation using the difference between the whole sample mean $\bar{x}_A$ and each subsample mean $\bar{x}_i$.

For a particular sample, say $a_i$, let us assume one-half of the data points are below the sample mean, and one-half are above the sample mean.

Because we can recover the sample $A$ mean from the data, we can use this new calculate the difference between the sample $A$'s mean and the subsample mean. This can then be used to attempt a recovery of the sample $A$'s standard deviation.

Let $d_i$ be the difference of a particular subsample from the overall sample mean $\bar{x}_A$, and let $s_i$ be the subsample standard deviation. Then

$$
s_A = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{2}n_1(d_1 + s_1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}n_1(d_1 - s_1)^2 \\+ \frac{1}{2}n_2(d_2 + s_2)^2 + \frac{1}{2}n_2(d_2 - s_2)^2 \\+ ... + \frac{1}{2}n_m(d_m + s_m)^2 + \frac{1}{2}n_m(d_m - s_m)^2}{n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_m - 1}}
$$

**Recover the Median**

I see no straightforward way for this to be accurate. We do have an idea of the dispersion and the difference between the mean and the median for each sample so I do have glimmers of possibilities but I have not thought deeply or can see a very obvious path.

**My Question for Cross Validated**

Can anyone comment on these strategies, offer their expertise, or point me to some resources?

Comment: I believe all these questions have been answered here, so one resource is our site search.

Comment: I did a quick search but mainly hit on examples where histograms were available. I struggled to find anything that fits my scenario?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43159, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30495, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12251, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151947, etc.  Use the name of a statistic, such as "median," "quantile," or "variance" in a search along with a keyword like "combine" or "pool".  I'm getting hundreds of hits--not all of which are appropriate, of course, but many look useful.

Comment: thank you whuber, I have found a lovely resource here: http://www.burtonsys.com/climate/composite_standard_deviations.html I will perhaps post an answer for the standard deviation

Answer (score 0):

- Mean: You answered yourself
- Standard deviation: Find first a pooled variance, see [How to calculate pooled variance of two or more groups given known group variances, means, and sample sizes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/how-to-calculate-pooled-variance-of-two-or-more-groups-given-known-group-varianc)
- Median: This is more difficult, see [Is it possible to calculate Q1, Median, Q3, StDev from already aggregated data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151947/is-it-possible-to-calculate-q1-median-q3-stdev-from-already-aggregated-data),   [Weighted median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167977/weighted-median),   [Calculate one median for data from five experimental repetitions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/39299/calculate-one-median-for-data-from-five-experimental-repetitions)