# Variance of a set of sample S from the means and variances of 2 partitions S1 and S2 (S=S1 U S2)

Tags: variance, sampling

Suppose that 2 persons collect samples of a random variable X.
Each of them come up with :
 - the number of observations
 - the mean
 - the variance

How can we calculate the variance of all the observations ?
Is there an exact calculus or an approximation.

Comment: Does this Q&A http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163179/recover-true-statistics-for-a-union-of-subsamples-only-data-available-are-summ?noredirect=1&lq=1 help, especially the links provided in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can compute exactly (and elegantly) the variance.
The variance is the sum of 
 - The average of the variance within each group 
 - The variance of the means (weighted by the number of observations)

Notice that a similar result exists for mutual information

All the theory is there :
http://www.burtonsys.com/climate/composite_standard_deviations.html